# ZF1 DB Select with Inner Join

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, inner-join

I'm having difficulty in creating a select query using an inner join the Zend Framework way.

I have looked at the manual and can't work out how to write the following statement:

```
SELECT m.user_id, m.timestamp, m.status
FROM (
     SELECT user_id, max( timestamp ) AS timestamp
     FROM timeclock_clockings
     GROUP BY user_id
     ) AS x
INNER JOIN timeclock_clockings AS m ON m.timestamp = x.timestamp
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using `Zend_Db_Expr()` and creating two `$select` instances.

```
$db = new Model_TimeclockClockings(); // or whatever yours is named

$nested = $db->select()
    ->from('timeclock_clockings', array('user_id', 'max(timestamp) AS timestamp'))
    ->group('user_id');

$select = $db->select()
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false) // required for joins
    ->from(array('x' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . (string) $nested . ')')))
    ->join(array('m' => 'timeclock_clockings'), 'm.timestamp = x.timestamp', array());

echo $select; // this should look like your query
```

That's about it.  There are actually several other similar questions like this on SO.  But I figured perhaps you were having trouble making sense of it.

Note that `join()` is an `INNER JOIN`, you can also use `joinLeft()` for `LEFT JOIN`.  Or `joinRight()` etc etc.

[More info on joins here.](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.join)